# post_max_size, max_execution_time and the impact on server load/memory usage

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, lamp

I've been searching for an answer to this online, but have come up with nothing so far. I know my way around a LAMP stack, but it's not my specialty - but something I've been working on has thrown up this question:

Theoretically speaking, if I set high values for the following in .htaccess (example values below), what effect does this have on the server if these limits never come close to being reached?

```
php_value post_max_size 1000M
php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
php_value max_execution_time 6000000
php_value max_input_time 6000000
```

Essentially, I understand what these values are for and what they do, but I'm trying to ascertain what happens if they are set high but the server never even comes close to those values.

In other words, does the simple fact that these values are high increase the load or memory usage on the server?

Or, another way of putting it, if post_max_size and upload_max_filesize are set at 1000M, but I only ever upload 100k images, does this increase server memory usage, even though I'm not posting huge files?

Similarly, if max_execution_time and max_input_time are given high values, does this increase memory usage even though every script executes long before this (ie in < 1s)?

Does that make sense? Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Thanks

Comment: No, PHP will not allocate automatically 1GB of RAM for every PHP process, it that's what you're asking. It should be fairly easy to verify.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. The issue is that I'm having a discussion with the server admin guy here at work who's claiming that high values will bring the server down periodically, even when there are no scripts or uploads that come anywhere near those limits. I think he's wrong - but then this is his job, so I can only assume he knows more than me and is correct! I just can't find any other evidence for this. :o/

Comment: It will be easier to DOS you this way. I only need to send 20 post requests simultaneously with 1GB of data and your server is probably out of memory (if it has less than 20GB).

Comment: Well, he's probably not completely wrong. If you allow 1 GB worth of raw POST data that could eventually lead to a `$_POST` array with all that data in the internal format used by PHP (multiplied by the simultaneous requests): that can definitively cause problems. (File uploads per-se work differently because PHP won't load actual files in memory.)

Comment: @RolandStarke Yep, fair point re DOS, but the server sits behind an authentication layer which routes all traffic before it even hits the server. Only a small group of users have access, so unlikely to be DOS'ed.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Agreed that allowing huge amounts of raw POST data would cause an issue, but this hasn't happened. His actual words are "raising the input/execution times [to high values] puts the webserver into an invalid state" - so he's suggesting that just having high values for these settings will nerf the server, even if these values never come close to being reached.

Comment: That's just not the case. I'd be easy to build a small counter-example with a local test server where you allow 100GB of everything and them hit the server with empty [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/programs/ab.html) requests while the monitoring tool of his choice is on screen.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks - yep, that could be an interesting 5 minutes. :o)

Comment: Roland makes a good point about DOS - but this ASSUMES that the corresponding values in the webserver config are equal or greater - most webserver configs limit the size and duration of requests to much lower values. And no, it won't have other side effects.